# ImportError: No module named happybase

Tags: python, mapreduce, hbase, happybase

I have a mapreduce program that connects to Hbase using happybase. I am getting the following error
File

```
/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/aprakash/appcache/application_1407169690715_0025/container_1407169690715_0025_01_000002/./testhappybase.py, line 9, in <module>
import happybase
ImportError: No module named happybase
```

When i run the program independently i am able to import happybase. Below command shows how i run my hadoop job

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -file
/home/aprakash/testhappybase.py -mapper /home/aprakash/testhappybase.py -file 
/home/aprakash/workspace/reducer.py -reducer /home/aprakash/workspace/reducer.py -input 
/user/aprakash/flume-channel/apache_access_combined/* -output /user/aprakash/flume-channel-output2
```

I see the happybase module under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/happybase`

Comment: Did you find solution to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the machines where the map reduce jobs are executed don't have Happybase installed?

Comment: I have hbase installed, but still I am getting error. Any idea on any other reasons. Thanks!